# ASP.NET/SQLServer - save filesnames with special characters converts the saved filename...why?

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, sql-server-2008-r2, utf

I have a strange problem.  I have a ASP.NET app which is storing files.  I have a table (SQL 2008 R2) where I store the file information on files which are uploaded by my users.

Once in awhile, when I store a filename from an international user with a special character, the name is converted when stored in the database table:
Example original filename: Łinename.mov
Stored filename: Linename.mov

When I retrieve the filename to build my path/file string, the names don't match and my file is not found.

The table stores the filename as nvarchar, and I thought that would allow unicode characters.

Any ideas?  I would prefer to store the original filename, and not rename the file on the server.

**EDIT:
I think the issue is that the character in question is not in the UTF-8 character set.
I solved this by keeping my life simple: I support UTF-8, and if the file is converted when stored as UTF-8, that is my server filename.**

Comment: What's the table schema? Sounds like an encoding problem?

Answer (score 1):

`NVARCHAR` does allow Unicode, but what you haven't said is how the inserts are made to the database -- it's entirely possible the translation isn't happening at SQL Server but is happening in the ASP.NET application.

Run SQL Profiler against the database and attempt to store a file with a non-ASCII character and see what is actually being executed against the database. If Profiler shows a translated name, then the problem is within ASP.NET. Otherwise SQL Server is doing something odd.

Check this, and then edit your question to report back results.

Comment: thank you.  perhaps my question wasn't the best, but i just had a problem i needed to solve.  i did what you suggested (my store went from ASP.NET -> WCF -> ado.net -> MSSQL), and it was converted from step 1.  I think the character in question was not in the UTF-8 list of characters.  My solution was to store using UTF-8, and adjust the filename on the server to be identical to what is in the database.

Comment: The character will be in the UTF-8 character set (every character is in the UTF-8 charset), so it's not that that's lost it. How did the bytes come in from the network? It should be possible to trace whereabouts the translation is happening.